# I don't know how to disable a declaration after a certain breakpoint

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the main class there's `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` which divides the whole section in half (`sidebar` and `content` classes are nested in that `main` class element). However, **after reaching 900px it leaves an empty space and stays at the top of the section leaving the other half empty**.

I'd like the main section to fill up the remaining space after reaching that certain breakpoint and I'm stuck.

This is a big one and this might land me the first internship ever, so I'd be really grateful if somebody helped me find a solution!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1A1C22;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #6C757D;
}

.content__box {
  background-color: #343A40;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.main {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 400px 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .content {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/1.css">
  <title>Layout & RWD</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header"></header>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="sidebar"></section>

    <section class="content">
      <article class="content__box"></article>
      <article class="content__box"></article>
      <article class="content__box"></article>
      <article class="content__box"></article>
      <article class="content__box"></article>
      <article class="content__box"></article>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: pls add your html too... after 900px you are changing `grid-template-columns` and again at 1200px

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above 900px you have two columns in addition to the two rows you have due to `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr`. You can reset this to a single column by adding `grid-template-rows: auto` targeting above 900px - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1A1C22;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #6C757D;
}

.content__box {
  background-color: #343A40;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.main {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .main { /* changed from 'main' to '.main' for specificity reasons */
    grid-template-rows: auto; /* added */
    grid-template-columns: 400px 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .content {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<main class="main">
  <section class="sidebar"></section>
  <section class="content">
    <article class="content__box"></article>
    <article class="content__box"></article>
    <article class="content__box"></article>
    <article class="content__box"></article>
    <article class="content__box"></article>
    <article class="content__box"></article>
  </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: I used ```grid-template-rows: auto``` earlier. I thought that it won't solve the case, but turns out I targeted the element itself instead of the class. Thanks!